# How to combine visual output from multiple windows

Tags: windows

Is there an application that will input the visual display of one or more windows / applications and output them in one window. Similar to a snip tool but in real time. Im looking to combine the visual output of two or three windows of an application into one window. How might y'all approach this problem?

Currently nothing yet.

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Maybe your question is out of the scope of SO. Here, you have to submit code you have written, with which you encounter a technical issue.